# How Nested JavaScript Loops Naturally Break

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a question about how nested loops work in JavaScript.

Imagine I have while() loop ... and inside of that is a for() loop. Each has its own separate ending conditions (see below for a schematic).

My question is this: will the while() loop stop the INSTANT its ending condition is met--even if the for() loop within it is not yet finished? Here is an example.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < somenumber){
    for(var j=0; j < othernumber; j++){
       somecode();
       i++:
    }
}
```

The code seems to be working, but I want to make sure I understand how these structures are supposed to work. The goal is to get the while loop (and thus also the for loop within) to stop the instant that 'i' has reached 'somenumber', even if j has not yet reached 'othernumber'.

Comment: Add some logging and test it out

Comment: First your `while` begins. Then the for loop starts. The for loop keeps going until it goes to one less than `othernumber`. Once this happens, your `while` loop starts again. Then the `for` loop fires again. This keeps happening until `i = somenumber`

Comment: It might help to console.log the values inside the `while` and `for`, to see what really is happening. Alternatively, I suggest drawing a table on a piece of paper and writing down a value chart.

Comment: The condition is tested each time execution hits it - this goes for `while` and `for`.

Comment: The `while` loop ONLY gets to test its condition WHEN the `for` loop is done.  So, the while loop isn't even part of the operation while the inner `for` loop is running.  Only when the `for` loop is done does the `while` loop again get to test its condition and decide if it will go another iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `labels` and the `break` command to exit a parent loop directly:

```js
var x = 0, y=0;
b1: {
  while (x++ < 5){
    b2: {
      for(y=0; y < 3; y++){
        if (y === 1){
           x = 2;
           break b1;
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
console.log(`x=${x}  y=${y}`)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you test the code and see what it does. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5tae95fg/) I tested with arbitrary numbers and it seems to show that the while loop does not terminate the instant the condition is met. It lets the job finish. Here's an explanation:

Initially, the condition is true, so it goes into the while loop. Once in the while loop, it doesn't check if the condition is true until the next iteration, meaning it won't stop executing the for loop even if the condition is false. Here's the test code:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 5){
    for(var j=0; j < 10; j++){
       console.log(j + ", iter= " + i);
       i++;
    }
}
```

This yields:

```
0, iter= 0
1, iter= 1
2, iter= 2
3, iter= 3
4, iter= 4
5, iter= 5
6, iter= 6
7, iter= 7
8, iter= 8
9, iter= 9
```

From the output above, we see the for loop doesn't end. It keeps on going because, although the while loop's condition is false, it doesn't check if it's true until the next iteration, allowing the for loop to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I [tested it for you](http://jsbin.com/vewevehugu/edit?js,console,output):

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 10){
    for(var j=0; j < 12; j++){
       somecode(j);
       i++;
    }
    console.log('i',i);
}

function somecode(j) {
  console.log('in the for loop', j);
}
```

The entire `for` loop is executed, and then the final `console.log` in the `while` loop is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Each loop will check the condition at the end of the current iteration (when the loop reaches the closing bracket). The only way to stop the **while** loop inside the **for** loop is to make something like this:

```
for(var j=0; j < othernumber; j++){
   somecode();
   i++;
   if (!(i < somenumber)) break; //it exits the for loop
}
```

When you exit the for loop and reach the closing bracket of the while loop, it will check the while condition and exit from the loop